# Can you have an approximation that is higher than the optimal for a maximum value and a lower than the optimal for a minimum value?

Tags: approximation

I was reading [this page](https://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/ApproximationAlgorithms.html) on approximation ratios and the author says that for a problem looking for a:

- **maximum**, an approximation algorithm will give us a value **lower than this optimal maximum**
- **minimum**, an approximation algorithm will give us a value **higher than this optimal minimum**

Is it possible to get the opposite?

- an approximation algorithm will give us a value **higher  than this optimal maximum**
- an approximation algorithm will give us a value **lower than this optimal minimum**

If they exist,

- why would such algorithms not be used (as I don't see them mentioned)?
- Isn't getting a range with $\pm$ of the optimal good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, by definition of a [maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Definition): it means that no other solution has higher value (and same thing for minimum).

Answer (score 2):

In a maximization problem w.r.t. some measure $m$, the *optimal* value is the maximum value $m(s)$ attainable among all feasible solutions $s$.

It is meaningless to ask for an algorithm that returns a feasible solution $s'$ such that $m(s') > m(s)$ since no such $s'$ exists.

The case of minimization problems is symmetric.